# Unitary equivalence between Hermitian operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, linear-algebra, quantum-computer, trace

Take two (non-zero) Hermitian operators $A$ and $B$. I want to proof that there exists no unitary operator $W$ such that:
$$W^{\dagger}AW = A + B$$
For my research I proved this for some specific case that involves symmetries. However I would like to know whether there is a general proof of this statement. If not, are there any conditions on $A$ and $B$ so it is true. 
So far I tried solving it with properties of the trace and unitary gates:
\begin{align}
Tr(A) = Tr(A) + Tr(B) &\rightarrow Tr(B) = 0 \\ 
Tr(A^2) = Tr(A^2) + Tr(B^2) + 2\cdot Tr(AB) &\rightarrow Tr(B^2) + 2\cdot Tr(AB) = 0
\end{align}
And so on. But this does not give me any contradiction e.g. $B = 0$ or something
Hence, my question is can $A$ and $A+B$ be unitarily equivalent?

Edit: included the non-zero condition

Comment: I don't think that this is true in general. Take any hermitian $A$ and $B=0$ as well as $W=\mathbb I$, for example.

Comment: It is also true if $A \neq 0$ and $B = 0$. However this is trivial.

Comment: If you restrict yourself to finite-dimensional matrices the answer is given by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specht%27s_theorem.

Answer (score 7):

The time evolution of the position operator of a free particle in quantum mechanics (Hamiltonian $H=P^2/2m$) is a nice counterexample:

$ e^{iHt/\hbar} X e^{-iHt/\hbar} = X + P t/m$,

with $A=X$ (position operator at time $t=0$), $B= P t/m$ (momentum operator $P$ times $t/\hbar$) and $W= \exp(-iHt/\hbar)$ (time evolution operator).

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple counter-example:
$$e^{iaP/\hbar}Xe^{-iaP/\hbar}=X+a$$
where $X$ is the position operator, $P$ is the momentum operator,
and $a$ is a constant.

Answer (score 4):

A nice counterexample has already been presented.

More generally, for any $W$ of the form $e^{X}$, where $X$ is an element of a Lie algebra, it follows from [an identity related to the BCH formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#An_important_lemma_and_its_application_to_a_special_case_of_the_Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula) that

$e^X A e^{-X} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{[(X)^n, A]}{n!}$.

So in such cases (as in the examples) the statement will clearly fail if $A$ and $X$ do not commute, and their commutator is also Hermitian.

Comment: This doesn't affect the main point, but I find the notation $[X^n,A]$ for $ad_X^n(A)$ rather misleading. (In the Wikipedia article they write $[(X)^n,A]$ which is maybe somewhat better...)

Comment: @Noiralef fair comment, I have edited the post